# Are Win32 InterlockedIncrement and InterlockedExchange atomic across processes?

Tags: linux, windows, gcc, atomic, atomic-swap

MSDN says that the interlocked functions provide a simple mechanism for synchronizing access to a variable that is shared by multiple threads.

I am not sure if they work across threads of multiple processes if the variable is in the shared memory of the processes.

Similarly what about GNU GCC compiler intrinsic: __sync_add_and_fetch and __sync_lock_test_and_set?

Comment: Short answer - yes. They're implemented with CPU instructions that guarantee atomic operations across cores. But I'm unable to list any references so I'm not giving an official answer.

Comment: Actually MSVC has intrinsic as well, `_InterlockedIncrement` and `_InterlockedExchange`. They are faster than a function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is essentially two questions for two different answers.

1. For `__sync_XXX` builtins in GCC answer is yes.

Refer to any online doc like [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html), where described, that these builtins are normally issuing full barrier, preventing even internal speculating loads inside processor pipeline. Every and all multi-thread, multi-process, etc. shared memory is safe with them.

2. I know nothing about Windows InterLockedXXX functions. But [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915358.aspx) knows, and says:

> The threads of different processes can use this mechanism if the variable is in shared memory

So both answers are "yes".